# How much accountability do deputies in the lowest levels of the government in China face to the Chinese citizenry?

Tags: china, government

> Rory Truex, a researcher of Chinese politics at Princeton University,
> states that "the CCP tightly controls the nomination and election
> processes at every level in the people's congress system...the tiered,
> indirect electoral mechanism in the People's Congress system ensures
> that deputies at the highest levels face no semblance of electoral
> accountability to the Chinese citizenry."[8]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_China

How much accountability do deputies in the lowest levels of the government in China face to the Chinese citizenry? The quote seemed to suggest a varying degree of accountability, with no accountability at the highest level and some accountability at the lowest level, but how accountable are the officials in the lowest levels of government, and how is accountability is ensured at the lowest levels?